# Migrating MediaWiki Sites over to Windows Sharepoint Services Wiki

Tags: sharepoint, migration, wiki, mediawiki

Had anybody found a way to migrate MediaWiki pages over to WSS Wikis? We just put up Sharepoint 2007 and while it appears to meet our needs, it doesn't appear to be any tool provided by Microsoft to migrate MediaWiki pages over to WSS wikis.

Comment: Often it is reasons such as lack of such tools that cause users to move from closed-source to open-source.  Why are you leaving MediaWiki?

Comment: We are looking to do the same thing, sharepoint offers more than mediawiki and we don't want to maintain two different wikis

Comment: I hope this works out for you. I've really got my doubts because I have not heard good things about the wiki part of Sharepoint (though I've heard better reviews of the other functionality).

Answer (score 4):

Create aspx File and add template of wikipage Library page in source and then migrate as Wikipage library of sharepoint 2007 or 2010

Answer (score 3):

There is no such tool provided by Microsoft at this time.

There is one being developed though in the [SharePoint Community Kit](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/06/18/community-kit-for-sharepoint-2-0-pre-release-announcement.aspx).

> **Wiki Import/Export Tool**
>
> The EWE team is at a very early stage of designing an import/export tool for the SharePoint wiki. The goal is for this tool to be able to import from other wiki products such as FlexWiki, MediaWiki, and TWiki, and Confluence and also from Word and OneNote as well as to export to Word via HTML (per page) and MHTML (entire wiki) formats.
>
> For this CKS 2.0 pre-release, the EWE team is making available a fairly stable build of the FlexWiki Import Tool, for which the source code was graciously donated by Michael Cheng, a developer in the SharePoint product group. This is a one-off tool that will ultimately be converted to a plug-in for the Wiki Import/Export Tool, so if you’re currently using FlexWiki, please test the tool and provide feedback.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to get Twiki into SharePoint. The biggest problem is programmatically creating the topics/pages inside SharePoint. I've documented my findings here : [sites.google.com/site/sharepointwikiuploader](http://sites.google.com/site/sharepointwikiuploader/)
Might save some time.

Answer (score 2):

There is a commercial tool for this: [Metalogix Migration Manager for Blogs and Wikis](http://www.metalogix.net/Products/Migration-Manager-for-Blogs-and-Wikis/)

Haven't testes it yet, but will post my experience when I do.

Answer (score 1):

I created a php script that reads an xml file created by Mediawiki's dumpBackup.php and dumps out text suitable for pasting into new Sharepoint wiki pages. I posted it in a [google code project](http://code.google.com/p/wiki-to-sharepoint/). In combination with Grant Traynor's method this could solve the problem.

Comment: eric.worden: are you accepting questions about this project?

Answer (score -1):

You can't expect even remotely similar functionality from such imported pages.  See http://wikiworks.com/enterprise-mediawiki-vs-sharepoint.html for an explanation of why you might want to reconsider this kind of migration.  You will lose 1. reliable infinite versioning and archiving 2. easy multi-author editing 3. all the capabilities of mediawiki extensions, over 2000 at last count.

In some businesses, e.g. insurance, law firms or accounting, losing 1. could have legal implications.

If your intent however is to simply make pages visible in SharePoint that are maintained in MediaWiki, then, you can do that by configuring SharePoint to search within the mediawiki - addressed by some other questions here on StackExchange.