# Mediawiki to sharepoint migration

Tags: bash, powershell, sharepoint, migration, mediawiki

Anyone has a local script (bash/powershell/any) that can copy data from a mediawiki page and paste it to a share point basic template?

if its easy lets just consider as copying a web page (MW) data including images etc and paste that to destination (sharepoint) location.

I have seen the responses from [Migrating MediaWiki Sites over to Windows Sharepoint Services Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148619/migrating-mediawiki-sites-over-to-windows-sharepoint-services-wiki/77083412#77083412) however this is very old post, so thinking if anyone has any recent exp to share?

Any inputs would be appreciated.